# How to vary the range of a potentiometer...is this even possible?

Tags: resistors, timer, 555, potentiometer

I am a total noob so apologize if this doesn't belong here but I haven't had any luck finding an answer to this...

I have a simple circuit with two 555 timers...similar to an Atari Punk Console. I have a switch in my circuit to switch between a headphone jack and a built in speaker (I know there's switchcraft plugs that do this. I just don't have one yet).

Anyway, the problem is the audio level/volume range is great through headphones  with a 50k pot, but switching to my small 8 ohm speaker the output isn't loud enough unless I switch to a 2k pot. But then with the 2k pot, audio level through my headphones is deafening.

I guess my question is, is there any (relatively simple) way to have the same pot utilize one range when running through one output path and a different range when going out another?

Does this even make sense?

Or am I thinking about this all wrong?

Incredibly grateful for any input.

Thank you!!![image]

Comment: Linear pots are not used here and Audio taper or logarithmic pots are better for UX.   But current for 8 Ohms MAY burn out Pot contact so it is used on input, not output.

Comment: BTW you may be able to see in the photo that I tried adding a 220k resistor in series with the headphone jack output but all that did was lower the entire level and essentially nullify the 2k pot.

Comment: Move pot to input using source to pins 1 or 3 and output from 2 with other pin common ground.  If numbered Pot wiper goes from 1 to 3 in CW direction. with 3 as input and 1 = gnd and 2 output using a LOG pot.

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 thanks! Very excited to try that out and it almost seemed to be working until I smelt burning and realized I burned out my 2k pot. Not sure exactly what I did wrong there...may need to sleep on it and try again tomorrow. Definitely going to look into the other pot types you mentioned as well. Thanks immensely for the input!

Comment: Put resistors in series to shift the range, put them in parallel to make them smaller and non linear.

Comment: if input is at V/2 DC then pot common goes to same DC voltage not ground. but if you wired to output which drives more power with V+/2 DC then it can draw too much current .. draw schematic of pot before you install new dual stereo log pot